# Next.js complains of unconfigured hostname for Next/Image, but it actually is

Tags: reactjs, next.js

hope you are well.

With Next.js 13.0.5, I've been trying to use the Next/Image component with an external source (Amazon S3 through CloudFront).

```
<Image src={"https://d2ss8eaptdxs3l.cloudfront.net/profile_pictures/default.jpg"}
     width={200}
     height={200}
     className="rounded-full"
/>
```

However, Next is complaining that I haven't configured the external hostname in next.config.js...

```
Error: Invalid src prop (https://d2ss8eaptdxs3l.cloudfront.net/profile-pictures/default.jpg) on `next/image`, hostname "d2ss8eaptdxs3l.cloudfront.net" is not configured under images in your `next.config.js`
See more info: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/next-image-unconfigured-host
```

... while I actually did like so:

```
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  swcMinify: true,
  images: {
    remotePatterns: [
      {
        protocol: "https",
        hostname: "d2ss8eaptdxs3l.cloudfront.net",
        port: "",
        pathname: "/**",
      },
    ],
  },
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

I've also tried the < 12.3.0 variation as described in the docs, with no success. https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/next-image-unconfigured-host

Could anyone help me out? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. My issue was that I was exporting two `module.exports` in `next.config.js`:

```
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  swcMinify: true,
  images: {
    remotePatterns: [{
      protocol: "https",
      hostname: "d2ss8eaptdxs3l.cloudfront.net",
      port: "",
      pathname: "/**"
    }]
  },
  webpack(config) {
    const fileLoaderRule = config.module.rules.find(
      (rule) => rule.test && rule.test.test(".svg"),
      );
      fileLoaderRule.exclude = /\.svg$/;
      config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.svg$/,
        loader: require.resolve("@svgr/webpack"),
      });
      return config;
  },
}

module.exports = nextConfig

module.exports = {
  webpack(config) {
    const fileLoaderRule = config.module.rules.find(
      (rule) => rule.test && rule.test.test(".svg"),
      );
      fileLoaderRule.exclude = /\.svg$/;
      config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.svg$/,
        loader: require.resolve("@svgr/webpack"),
      });
      return config;
  },
};
```

I've changed that to only one including both webpack and images configurations, and everything ran fine since.

```
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  swcMinify: true,
  images: {
    remotePatterns: [{
      protocol: "https",
      hostname: "d2ss8eaptdxs3l.cloudfront.net",
      port: "",
      pathname: "/**"
    }]
  },
  webpack(config) {
    const fileLoaderRule = config.module.rules.find(
      (rule) => rule.test && rule.test.test(".svg"),
      );
      fileLoaderRule.exclude = /\.svg$/;
      config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.svg$/,
        loader: require.resolve("@svgr/webpack"),
      });
      return config;
  },
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```